# Capture Apple watch data to server using laravel

Tags: ios, laravel, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to capture apple watch data so that it can be saved on our server and user can use it in their app. Is there any api which can be easily integrated with laravel to collect the apple watch data. Do we need some IOS app also for that because it will be better if we can directly fetch the data. Anyone have an idea what is the best solution. Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand how it could be possible for a laravel app to access data on a watch without a app on the watch that is sending the data you need...

Comment: Which data?  Yes, you will need an app on the watch

Comment: @Paulw11 : Data is like pulse rate etc. is there any third party api also for accessing this data?

Comment: there is no 3rd party api. You will need to look at HealthKit which is part of WatchOS. You will need to write a watch app to access this data.

Comment: You can also access the data from HealthKit. Y writing an app that runs on the paired phone, which might be easier than writing a watch app

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks for the suggestions, So i will be using laravel (PHP) application for server side it will be getting data from Healthkit api which will be saved by ios watch app that will be developed?

Comment: I guess. It is pretty typical to connect mobile apps to servers using some sort of RESTful api.